# How can I catch all exceptions in IOS 5?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I am battling an issue in which my application crashes while launching. When trying to run my application in the iPhone simulator it immediately breaks in the main function. I cannot determine why this is. In my applicationDelegate I am attempting to catch the exception by using NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler.

```
    void uncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *exception){
    NSLog(@"%@",[exception reason]);
}
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{  
    NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&uncaughtExceptionHandler);
    return YES;
}
```

This does not seem to help as my application still breaks in main() and never seems to call application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

I have also tried to set the global breakpoint, objc_exception_throw at the user level. Again the application just seems to break on main()

Can someone provide me with some tips or tricks I can use to try and track down this problem?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XCode, go to your Breakpoint Navigator (cmd+6).

In the bottom left click on the plus button, click on add Exception Breakpoint. Select All exceptions and On Throw.

This should create a breakpoint that will help you identify where any exceptions are being generated.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying this but I cannot seem to get any detail about the exception. As you suggested I created a break point for All exceptions and even added a sound. The sound plays. How do generate a stack trace or something useful to debug this? It simply breaks on the main().

Comment: What the breakpoint should do is break right before the exception is actually thrown. If you step through you'll see the exception be thrown and can see what's going on in the console.

Comment: The console only shows this error and the breakpoint. breakpoint 1 - "objc_exception_throw" resolved
Pending breakpoint 2 - "objc_exception_throw" resolved
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c

Catchpoint 3 (exception thrown).

Comment: maybe this will help http://www.buildingiphoneapps.com/2010/09/application-crashes-sigabrt-simple-case.html ?